# ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery} (at char 57), (line:3, col:21)

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I am trying to do a simple SPARQL query using RDFlib. 
I have created an RDF graph using Radlex ontology and I am trying to query in the graph
'''

```
g = Graph()
FOAF = rdflib.Namespace("http://radlex.org/RID/")
patient = rdflib.term.URIRef("http://localhost/rdf/patient/") 
n1 = Namespace("http://localhost/rdf/patient/") 

g.add( (patient, FOAF.RID13159, n1.age) )
g.add( (patient, FOAF.RID13159, n1.name) )
g.add( (patient, FOAF.RID13159, n1.gender) )

g.add( (n1.name,  FOAF.RID13160, Literal("Radha")))
g.add( (n1.age,   FOAF.RID13163, Literal('21')))
g.add( (n1.gender,FOAF.RID13164, Literal("F"))) 

result = g.serialize(format='turtle')

qres = g.query(
          """SELECT ?Subject
         WHERE {
                ?Subject FOAF.RID13163 "F". 
               }"""
          )
```

'''

and I get this error

```
 ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7aadbf996386> in <module>
     24              WHERE {
     25                     ?Subject FOAF.RID13163 "F".
---> 26                    }"""
     27               )
     28 # list( g.triples((None, FOAF.RID13160, None)) )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py in query(self, query_object, processor, result, initNs, initBindings, use_store_provided, **kwargs)
   1087 
   1088         return result(processor.query(
-> 1089             query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs))
   1090 
   1091     def update(self, update_object, processor='sparql',

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\processor.py in query(self, strOrQuery, initBindings, initNs, base, DEBUG)
     72 
     73         if not isinstance(strOrQuery, Query):
---> 74             parsetree = parseQuery(strOrQuery)
     75             query = translateQuery(parsetree, base, initNs)
     76         else:

ParseException: Expected {SelectQuery | ConstructQuery | DescribeQuery | AskQuery} (at char 57), (line:3, col:21)
```

**I don't understand what does this error mean**

Comment: 1.) it's a plain Python string, what do you think happens with `FOAF.RID13163` ? 2.) you have double quotes inside, use single quotes

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it doesn't recognize a syntactically correct query form.

In your case, you need to map from rdflib's use of Python object attribute access for expressing prefixed names -- in your example, `FOAF.RID13163` -- to SPARQL's notation for prefixed names, which uses a colon. This means that `FOAF.RID13163` in Python translates to `FOAF:RID13163` in SPARQL. Otherwise, rdflib complains that it cannot find a valid query form.

Beyond this, there is another reason that your query will not run, even if you change `FOAF.RID13163` to `FOAF:RID13163`: the `FOAF` namespace prefix will not be recognized by the query. If you add the line `g.bind("FOAF", FOAF)` before running your query, then your query will run.

Once your query runs, there are two other things I would like to point out. First, I think you mean for your predicate in the query triple to be `FOAF:RID13164` -- that will return one result. Second, `FOAF` is a built-in namespace for rdflib (`from rdflib.namespace import FOAF`), and refers to the well-known Friend of a Friend vocabulary. I suggest you use another name (`RID` in your case?) so as not to confuse others who might need to work with your code.